# IDL interface, C++, CORBA, I'm dealing with "conflicting return type specified for" and "invalid abstract return type for member function ‘virtual..."

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, corba, idl, omniorb

For over 3 days I've been dealing with CORBA and C++ and my app interface written in IDL.

My app interface looks like this:

```
#ifndef __FORUM_INTERFACE_IDL__
#define __FORUM_INTERFACE_IDL__

#include "Forum.idl"
typedef sequence<Forum> Forums;

interface ForumInterface
{
    Forums getForumList(in Forum f);
    Forums getUsersForumList(in long UsersID);
    void addNewTopic(in Forum f, in long UsersID, in string title);
};

#endif
```

**I "compile" it to *.hh and *.cc files by : omniidl -bcxx ForumInterface.idl**

My Forum-object (also defined in IDL) looks like:

```
#ifndef __FORUM_IDL__
#define __FORUM_IDL__

interface Forum
{
    long getForumID();
    void setForumID(in long id);
    string getForumName();
    void setFroumName(in string name);
    Forum getForumParent();
    void setForumParent(in Forum f);
};

#endif
```

**I "compile" it to *.hh and *.cc files by : omniidl -bcxx Forum.idl**

I tried to write an implementation of both Forum and ForumInterface. I started with Forum, here's definition of class FroumImpl:

```
#ifndef __FORUMIMPL_H__
#define __FORUMIMPL_H__

#include "Forum.hh"

class ForumImpl : public POA_Forum
{
    private :

        long id;
        char *name;
        ForumImpl parent;

    public :

        long getForumID();
        void setForumID(long id);
        char* getForumName();
        void setFroumName(const char* name);
        ForumImpl getForumParent();
        void setForumParent(ForumImpl f);
};

#endif
```

and it's declaration (for now it's empty):

```
#include "ForumImpl.h"

long ForumImpl::getForumID(){}
void ForumImpl::setForumID(long id){}
char* ForumImpl::getForumName(){}
void ForumImpl::setFroumName(const char* name){}
ForumImpl ForumImpl::getForumParent(){}
void ForumImpl::setForumParent(ForumImpl f){}
```

I tried to compile it,

```
g++ -c ForumImpl.cpp -I$OMNIORB_HOME/include -I$OMNIORB_HOME/include/omniORB4
```

but got errors:

> In file included from ForumImpl.cpp:1:0: ForumImpl.h:12:19: error:
>   field ‘parent’ has incomplete type ForumImpl.h:20:19: error:
>   conflicting return type specified for ‘virtual ForumImpl
>   ForumImpl::getForumParent()’ Forum.hh:161:21: error:   overriding
>   ‘virtual _objref_Forum* _impl_Forum::getForumParent()’
>   ForumImpl.h:20:19: error: invalid abstract return type for member
>   function ‘virtual ForumImpl ForumImpl::getForumParent()’
>   ForumImpl.h:6:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are
>   pure within ‘ForumImpl’: Forum.hh:162:16: note:  virtual void
>   _impl_Forum::setForumParent(Forum_ptr) ForumImpl.h:21:14: error: cannot declare parameter ‘f’ to be of abstract type ‘ForumImpl’
>   ForumImpl.h:6:7: note:   since type ‘ForumImpl’ has pure virtual
>   functions ForumImpl.cpp: In member function ‘virtual ForumImpl
>   ForumImpl::getForumParent()’: ForumImpl.cpp:7:11: error: invalid
>   abstract return type for member function ‘virtual ForumImpl
>   ForumImpl::getForumParent()’ ForumImpl.h:6:7: note:   since type
>   ‘ForumImpl’ has pure virtual functions ForumImpl.cpp: At global scope:
>   ForumImpl.cpp:8:42: error: cannot declare parameter ‘f’ to be of
>   abstract type ‘ForumImpl’ ForumImpl.h:6:7: note:   since type
>   ‘ForumImpl’ has pure virtual functions

the worst thing is I have no idea why this code gives me such errors ... I mean, I defined all of `ForumImpl` functions ... so any of them is virtual now. I spent hours and hours trying figure out what's wrong with this but have no clue :(

Could anyone help? **My files: http://www6.zippyshare.com/v/69552292/file.html I added to this tar archive a Makefile, so simply run command "make all" and this will do everything**.

I would be very grateful if anyone could tell my why I got those error and what to do to fix this, I really need it. Cheers:)

**EDIT:**

I changed my ForumImpl.h and ForumImpl.cpp:

```
#ifndef __FORUMIMPL_H__
#define __FORUMIMPL_H__

#include "Forum.hh"

class ForumImpl : public POA_Forum
{
    private :

        long id;
        char *name;
        ForumImpl *parent;

    public :

        long getForumID();
        void setForumID(long id);
        char* getForumName();
        void setFroumName(const char* name);
        ForumImpl* getForumParent();
        void setForumParent(ForumImpl *f);
};

#endif

#include "ForumImpl.h"
long ForumImpl::getForumID(){}
void ForumImpl::setForumID(long id){}
char* ForumImpl::getForumName(){}
void ForumImpl::setFroumName(const char* name){}
ForumImpl* ForumImpl::getForumParent(){}
void ForumImpl::setForumParent(ForumImpl *f){}
```

but this gave me those erros:

> g++ -c ForumImpl.cpp -IMNIORB_HOME/include
>   -IMNIORB_HOME/include/omniORB4 In file included from ForumImpl.cpp:1:0: ForumImpl.h:20:20: error: invalid covariant return
>   type for ‘virtual ForumImpl* ForumImpl::getForumParent()’
>   Forum.hh:161:21: error:   overriding ‘virtual _objref_Forum*
>   _impl_Forum::getForumParent()’

Comment: I haven't done any CORBA programming in the last 4 years, and don't recall the details, but the error indicates that the generated base class returns a `_objref_Forum*` but you return a `ForumImpl`. Also note that you cannot store a type inside itself (i.e. the `parent` member should probably be a pointer or *CORBA reference*)

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas: see my edit, it wasn't that ... :(

Comment: It still is that. You are returning a `ForumImpl*` where the base returns a `_objref_Forum*`. I don't recall the CORBA mapping to C++ but there is probably some typedef of `_objref_Forum` to a CORBA sanctioned type in the generated headers. That is the type that you should be using. Note that, the `ForumImpl` is the implementation of the service, but the CORBA reference is the client side (which is an object that takes a request, potentially serializes and sends it through the network, gets decoded by the ORB and dispatched to the implementation...).

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas: Its quite strange for me cause I have in my app class `GroupImpl` where I have: http://pastie.org/private/po5v8mynodcquaxzuekbkw and it compiles with no errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature for `ForumImpl::getForumParent()` should look like this:

```
Forum_ptr getForumParent();
```

For more information you should download the [IDL to C++ mapping document from the OMG website](http://www.omg.org/spec/CPP/1.3/). Also check out Henning & Vinowski's book *Advanced CORBA Programming with C++*.

Answer (score 1):

The method signatures in ForumImpl should match the base class as generated in Forum.hh. They should return just Forum. I don't know omniorb in detail, but TAO has hundreds of examples that use this, for example our bank example, you can also find that online at https://svn.dre.vanderbilt.edu/viewvc/Middleware/trunk/TAO/examples/Simple/bank/

Comment: I changed type to `Forum`, take a look: http://pastie.org/private/yzw8scie4xxezamolyjcpw but still have an error: http://pastie.org/private/sbobkbsrc6ckvnknjmsva