# Does idjl (Sun IDL compiler) support forward declaration?

Tags: java, corba, idl

I **have to** use *idlj* for my school project but in my idl files I also need to use forward declaration. Does anybody know if idlj support forward declaration? I tried to do this, but it gives errors:

> interface1.idl (line 34):  There is a forward reference to Class1, but
>   it is not defined.

Any ideas how to overcome this? I can't use any other idl compiler, unfortunately ... and I coudn't find any info about this.

**EDIT:**

interface1.idl:

```
interface SecondClass;

interface FirstClass
{
    //...
};
```

interface2.idl:

```
interface FirstClass;

interface SecondClass
{
    //...
};
```

> idlj -fclient interface1.idl

gives :

> interface1.idl (line 8):  There is a forward reference to SecondClass,
>   but it is not defined. };   ^

Comment: It almost certainly has to. You are probably getting the error because you never eventually define `Class1`. Without seeing your IDL it is impossible to say.

Comment: @Brian Neal: It's weird, please, take a look at my edit - I defined `Class1` (vel `FirstClass` now)

Comment: At some point the IDL translator needs to see the definition of SecondClass.

Comment: @Brian Neal: ok but here `include` is not the solution - if I use `include` directive I would have a cyclic dependency ... I can't have those both interfaces in one IDL file - is there any other solution?

Comment: At the bottom of interface1.idl you could #include interface2.idl so the IDL compiler can finally see what Second class is. It has to see the definition of SecondClass so it can generate the right code for FirstClass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**THIS VERSION OF MY CODE WORKED FINALLY (COMPILED WITH NO ERRORS) BUT I STILL DON'T KNOW HOW AND WHY ;P**

I dont know how and why but it finally compiled with no errors, take a look:

**File interface1.idl**

```
#ifndef __FIRSTCLASS_IDL__
#define __FIRSTCLASS_IDL__

#include "interface2.idl"

interface FirstClass
{
    typedef sequence<SecondClass> secondVector;
    FirstClass create();
};

#endif
```

**File interface2.idl**

```
#ifndef __SECONDCLASS_IDL__
#define __SECONDCLASS_IDL__

interface FirstClass;

interface SecondClass
{
    typedef sequence<FirstClass> firstVector;
    SecondClass create();
};

#include "interface1.idl"

#endif
```

I'm just a little bit confused why one `include` directive is at the top of the idl file, while the other one has to be at the bottom. Anybody knows that? Geez!

Comment: This is exactly what I told you to do in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
#ifndef _SecondClass
#define _SecondClass
#include "interface1.idl"
interface SecondClass
{
   typedef sequence<FirstClass> firstVector;
   SecondClass create();
};
#endif

#ifndef _FirstClass
#define _FirstClass
#include "interface2.idl"
interface FirstClass
{
   typedef sequence<SecondClass> secondVector;
   FirstClass create();
};
#endif
```

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11763036/idl-interface-c-corba-im-dealing-with-conflicting-return-type-specified-f). Use this pattern for all of your interdependent interfaces.

Comment: Whoops, I don't get it: I changed my code, as you sugested: http://pastie.org/private/mfhfe07igooquih55dfcfw and got errors: http://pastie.org/private/qnuyzoeunhsdklxf8d610q

Comment: I don't have an IDL compiler handy; you'll have to go back to your working version and tinker with it. Post results so others know what worked.

Comment: do you have Java installed? It comes with idlj (IDL) compiler right away. Ok I will edit my post and write there what worked

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with that ORB, but it should be possible. Just remember that if you forward declare a class, you must eventually provide the definition somewhere so the translator knows what to do.

For example:

```
interface SecondClass;  // forward declaration

interface FirstClass {

   SecondClass foo();
};

// now you must provide the IDL for SecondClass; 
// either write it out here or #include the appropriate IDL file
```

Comment: yeah I know that all but as I said: I can't include interfaces, I have to have one interface per one idl file.

Comment: @mazix Why can't you #include an interface? It will not cause a cyclic dependency. Failing that, why do you have to have one interface per IDL file? It can't be done any other way. You have to have both definitions in the same file, either by #include or just having 1 IDL file.

Comment: @mazix See for example http://documentation.progress.com/output/Iona/orbix/mainframe/6.2/pli/IDLinterfaces14.html